# Neo4j Query on multiple label and missing association

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can't claim I am new to cypher anymore as I am playing with it for over couple of month now, but still struggle with some type of queries. I was wondering if someone can help me with these type of queries.

Suppose if I have order data with the following multi labels nodes:

`(o:Order:Active:New)` or `(o:Order:Active:InProcess)` or `(o:Order:Active:Approved)` or `(o:Order:Closed)`

and have relationship as

`(c:Customer)-[:PLACED_ORDER]-(o)-[:APPROVED_BY]->(e:Employee), (o)-[:HAS_CONSTRAINTS]->(dc:DateConstraint)`

Assuming all of these nodes have InternalId property on it.

1. How can I find all the orders for a customer  that are `Active and New` or `Active and Inprocess` but not `Active and Approved`. Basically looking to query for multiple Labels.
2. How can I find all the orders that are **approved by someone else** i.e. orders approved by other employees than the InternalId of the employee I have.
3. How can i query for all the orders that **does not** have a constraints, i.e. missing `HAS_CONSTRAINTS` relationship

Regards
Kiran

Comment: In #2, what do you mean by "someone else"?

Comment: @cybersam: Here I mean to check all the approved orders by other employees. say if we have 2 Employees A, B and C, and if I log in as B, I want to see orders approved by A & C

Comment: What does "other employees" mean? Are you saying that you will pass in a parameter with identifying information for a particular employee?

Comment: @cybersam : I just edited the post to clarify this. basically Yes, assume that I have the InternalId of the employee B above and want to look for orders approved by A and C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. MATCH (o:Order) WHERE o:Active AND (o:New OR o:InProcess) RETURN o;
2. MATCH (o:Order)-[:APPROVED_BY]->(e) WHERE NOT e.InternalId = {InternalId} RETURN o;
3. MATCH (o:Order) WHERE NOT (o)-[:HAS_CONSTRAINTS]->() RETURN o;

In #2, I assume you are passing in an "InternalId" parameter.

Comment: I was still recovering from the fact as to how I missed the #2. 1 & 3 I had no clue that this could be done. Thanks.